# Feynman Two Loop Integrals

Tags: physics, wolfram-physics

Is there any reference suitable for a beginner that you recommend for learning two loop integrals evaluation by hand ( and/or some package) that you know of?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to provide some context for your question. How much of a beginner are you? Do you know QFT - if not, you can't just start in calculating two-loop diagrams.

Comment: The tree level QFT calculations are understood. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: FeynCalc (feyncalc.github.io) is a widely used package for Mathematica for computing Feynman diagrams.

Comment: Thanks much, Tom.